# Radar chart is not displaying the values accurately on the axis

Tags: r, radar-chart

I am trying to create a radar chart but the axis stops at 4 when the maximum I have given is 10. Any help is much appreciated.

I have taken a subset of the dataset from a .csv file. Below is the subset

```
datasample = structure(list(Score = 7.522, Whisker.high = 7.581728, Whisker.low = 7.462272, 
    GDP = 1.482383, Family = 1.551122, Health = 0.7925655, Freedom = 0.6260067, 
    Generosity = 0.3552805, TrustInGovernmentAndCorruption. = 0.4007701, 
    Dystopia.Residual = 2.3137), .Names = c("Score", "Whisker.high", 
    "Whisker.low", "GDP", "Family", "Health", "Freedom", "Generosity", 
    "TrustInGovernmentAndCorruption.",
    "Dystopia.Residual"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L))
```

The subset contains 10 columns and 1 row.

Code:

```
library(fmsb)

#data <- read.csv("~/Desktop/App-1/2017.csv")
#datasample <- data[2, 3:12]
datasample <- rbind(rep(10,12), rep(0,12), datasample)
radarchart(datasample, axistype = 1,
           pcol = rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9), pfcol = rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5, 0.5), plwd = 4,
           cglcol = "grey", cglty = 1, axislabcol = "grey",caxislabels = seq(0,20,1), cglwd = 0.8,
           vlcex = 0.8)
```

Here is the chart created:

The highest value in the subset (datasample) is 7.581728 but the chart does not display that value. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The radar plot you are generating has an axis that is percentages of the max data point (you can see these when you remove the `caxislabels` from your plot (you'll get 100%,75%,50%,25%). The values you are seeing around 3 are actually the ~7.5 values (on the 75% grid line).

One way to fix this so that the axis is as expected:

```
radarchart(datasample, axistype = 1,
           pcol = rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9), pfcol = rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5, 0.5), plwd = 4,
           cglcol = "grey", cglty = 1, axislabcol = "grey",
           caxislabels = seq(min(datasample),max(datasample),1), seg=length(seq(min(datasample),max(datasample),1))-1,
           cglwd = 0.8, vlcex = 0.8)
```